# Refresh a page without reloading with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm making a system to detect presence by QR Code with Django, and I need a way to display a image and text when a QR Code is detected without having to reaload the page, i saw something about HTMX but i couldn't do much with it.
There isn't much in the internet about using a if statement to do this.

**views.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import JsonResponse, StreamingHttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from django.views.decorators import gzip
from .models import *

def camera_feed(request):
    stream = CameraStreamingWidget()
    frames = stream.get_frames()
    return StreamingHttpResponse(frames, content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

class CameraStreamingWidget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(int(os.environ.get('CAMERA')))
        self.media_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "media", "images")
        
        # create "media/images" folder if doesn't exist
        if not self.media_path:
            os.mkdir(self.media_path)

    def get_frames(self):
        while True:
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            success, frame = self.camera.read()
            if not success:
                break
            else:
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                
                # Add text on top of the barcode if there is a barcode in the stream using opencv
                # convert camera frame to numpy array
                color_image = np.asanyarray(frame)

                # decode numpy array to check if there is a barcode in color_image
                # you can add a custom check here to verify if the qr code has right identifier information
                if decode(color_image):
                    for barcode in decode(color_image):
                        barcode_data = (barcode.data).decode('utf-8')

                        print(barcode_data)
                        # if barcode data exists
                        if barcode_data:

                            '''# save file as PNG if a QR code is detected
                            image = os.path.join(self.media_path, f"{barcode_data}.png")
                            cv2.imwrite(image, frame)
                            
                            # print info for debugging purpose
                            print('-'*50)
                            print('Saving image to media...')
                            print('-'*50)
                            print(f'Saved as: {image}')
                            print('-'*50)'''
                            
                            pts = np.array([barcode.polygon], np.int32)
                            pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
                            # draw polylines on the barcode
                            cv2.polylines(
                                img=color_image,
                                pts=[pts],
                                isClosed=True,
                                color=(0,255,0),
                                thickness=3
                            )
                            pts2 = barcode.rect
                            # put text on top of polylines
                            barcode_frame = cv2.putText(
                                img=color_image,
                                text=barcode_data,
                                org=(pts2[0], pts2[1]),
                                fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,
                                fontScale=0.1,
                                color=(0,0,255),
                                thickness=2
                            )
                            # encode the new barcode_frame that has polylines and barcode data text
                            _, buffer_ = cv2.imencode('.jpg', barcode_frame)
                            # convert barcode_frame to bytes
                            barcode_frame = buffer_.tobytes()
                            # yield output stream with polylines and barcode data text
                            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + barcode_frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
                # else, yield the normal camera stream
                else:
                    frame = buffer.tobytes()
                    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')



def detect(request):
    stream = CameraStreamingWidget()
    success, frame = stream.camera.read()
    if success:
        status = True
    else:
        status = False

    return render(request, 'detect_barcodes/detect.html', context={'cam_status': status})
```

**HTML template**

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <h2>Sistema de Presença de Aluno por QR Code</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {% if cam_status %}
        <h3>Status do fluxo da câmera: Ligada</h3>
        <img src="{% url 'camera_feed' %}" style="width: 540px; height: 400px;" />
        {% else %}
        <h3>Status do fluxo da câmera: a câmera não está acessível ou está ocupada</h3>
        <h5>Coisas para checar: </h5>
        <ul class="text-right list-inline">
            <li>Conexão USB?</li>
            <li>Número da câmera em seu arquivo .env?</li>
            <li>A câmera já está em uso?</li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $("#btn_ReadQRCode").on("click", function (e) {
        console.log("Ajax request triggered.");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'camera_feed' %}",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                dataType: "json",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.barcode_data !== null && data.barcode_data !== '') {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#txt_BarcodeData").html(data.barcode_data);
                    $("#lbl_LastModified").html(
                        "Last modified at: " + data.file_saved_at
                    );
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#txt_BarcodeData").html("");
                    $("#lbl_LastModified").html("<h3><em>No data or file not found. Scan barcode again.</em></h3>");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

(Sorry for my bad english, i used the tradutor)

Comment: I don't think Django has such a built-in feature. However, you can try using JavaScript or using a third-party package like [django-browser-reload](https://pypi.org/project/django-browser-reload/)

Comment: it needs to use JavaScript and function `fetch(url, data)` to send data to server and get result and later JavaScript has to put it in HTML. You can send image as string encoded with `base64` in JSON data (it is popular method in many APIs) and use `<img src="image/jpg;base64, ... string_with_image...">` to display it. I have only examples for `Flask` [web camera in browser - canvas - take image and upload to server](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server).

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet would probably to look into POSTing forms using `Ajax`+`Javascirpt/JQuery`, That would allow you to Submit the form and refreshing.

I'm not 100% sure on how you'd return the picture in Ajax though.

I've worked with barcodes before and what I've done is generate them in a folder `static/barcodes/encoded_barcode_text.png` then serve them using an image tag using that URL. Then you could run a Cron/Scheduled Task to clear that directory at some point

Answer (score 0):

you can use [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  to make async connection to the server using javascript websocket built in library
,you can read more through this [docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/asgi.html) for basic usage of django channels